# How can I return CORS headers for 404 errors in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm using .NET 7 and ASP.NET Core.

I have configured CORS headers and they are sent back to the client when everything is OK (200).

But for 404, CORS headers are not sent back.

When I return `return NotFound("Some message here")` I can't get that message in the client (Axios), because CORS headers are not present.

How can I configure that?

Comment: CORS controls access to web resources, and the 404 status code indicates that a requested resource or URL does not exist. What is the use case for controlling access to nonexistent resources?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the UseCors middleware in the configure method above the routing middleware in your startup.cs file.

for using UseCors install **"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors"** from nuget package

Example:

```
app.UseCors(options => {
        options.AllowAnyOrigin();
        options.AllowAnyMethod();
        options.AllowAnyHeader();
    });
```

the above middleware will add the CORS headers to all response including the 404 response.